MemoryCache Implementation for console application service
I’m trying to use the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory namespace to add application caching to a Net 8 console app. I have partway there but have hit a point where I can't figure out how to manage the cache once it's operational, with more than 1,000 items. In my GenericHostBuilder class I’ve setup the following caching options:
  private static void BuildMemoryCacheOptions(MemoryCacheOptions _MemoryCacheOptions)
  {
    _MemoryCacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions();
    _MemoryCacheOptions.Clock = new Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.SystemClock();
    _MemoryCacheOptions.SizeLimit = 1024 * 1024;
    _MemoryCacheOptions.TrackLinkedCacheEntries = false;
    _MemoryCacheOptions.ExpirationScanFrequency = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    _MemoryCacheOptions.CompactionPercentage = 0.15;
    _MemoryCacheOptions.TrackStatistics = true;
  }

And the GenericHostBuilder  implements it as a service.
_HostApplicationBuilder.Services.AddMemoryCache(BuildMemoryCacheOptions);

I then add it to my classes as a globally scoped variable during the constructor call, and as a singleton on a scoped service provider:
private _MemoryCache = _ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MemoryCache>();

I can then use it in a method to add cached items to the application cache, and save round trips to the Database, such as this:
 public Domain? AddAnyLengthName(ref TopLevelDomain _TLD, string _DomainName, bool _IsValidName)
 {
    Domain? _Domain = _Domain = null;
    MyDBContext _DbContext = _ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDBContext>();
    string _RootDomainName = DomainDTO.ConvertToRootDomainName(_DomainName);
    _Domain = new Domain(_RootDomainName, _TLD);
    _Domain.IsValidDomainName = _IsValidName;
    _DbContext.Domains.Add(_Domain);
    _DbContext.SaveChanges();

    Domain _CachedDomain = _MemoryCache.Set(_Domain.DomainName, _Domain);
    ICacheEntry _CacheEntry = _MemoryCache.CreateEntry(_CachedDomain);
    _CacheEntry.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
    return _Domain;
  }

All this works very well and the performance improvement has been dramatic. But, eventually the cache fills up and performance starts taking a hit. When the MemoryCache component comes out of the service container it’s type has chnaged to an IMemoryCache type, which is where I ran into my problems, as this interface has several missing properties and methods that are included with the MemoryCache class by default, and I've not yet found a solution to fix this.
IMemoryCache has a method, GetCurrentStatistics() and a property Count. The Count returns the number of items in the cache, but when I try to use GetCurrentStatistics() it's always null and there are no other properties or methods that allow me to iterate over the items in the cache.
So, at present I have no way to manage the cache contents.
On the other hand, if do not implement MemoryCache as a service and instead implement it directly in a class, and then pass it around as a parameter, I have access to these additional methods and properties that let me manage the cache contents, such as Clear() to clear all items from the cache, or enumerators that allow me to iterate over the cache contents, without having to know in advance what each key is for cached item.
My questions are:

Do I need to include other packages to the project to gain access to these properties and methods from an IMemoryCache instance?
Is there an MemoryCacheOption that I’m missing?
Could there be another way to implement this? Still as a service but with some additional properties and methods, perhaps wrapped in a custom class?
Something else I haven’t considered?

I even tried adding MemoryCache to my DbContextOptions like so:
_DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseMemoryCache(new MemoryCache(GetMemoryCacheOptions()));

but when I go to retrieve it, I can’t get to it using the ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(), so maybe there is another way to do this that I haven’t yet seen any documentation for.
This is my 1st time to use this component so I'm sure there are other ways to get to where I would like to be, I just haven't found a MS web page or blog that speaks to anything other than an ASP.NET implementation, and this is a console app, with no Web parts.
Thanks in advance for you ideas and suggestions.

After spending a couple of days trying to sort out the disconnect between MS Learn documentation on this component and what you see in the actual bits and runtime behavior, I read through the conversations exchanged between the team members that worked on this component.
From what I can gather, the problems were not in the base code for MemroyCache, but instead were deeper, down into the Net Framework itself, I'm running Net8. Unfortunately no specific details were given on that topic, making MemoryCache on some level, a black box. And in the places where the problems were severe, the decision was made to tie off some properties and methods, making them unavailable or having them return null or zero.
I'm sure there are developers smarter than I am, who can work around these problems and still make it work for thier particular circumstances, but that requires time and effort that I can't commit to.
My alternative were:

Download MemoryCache the code from Github and develope my own work arounds.
Go to NuGet and use a package published by another developer.

I opted for option 2
Still, for the parts of MemoryCache that did work as advertised, the perforamce improvements for my application were dramatic, cutting processing time from several minutes to just seconds. So the core goals of MemoryCache remain solid and adventageous for any application dealing with large amounts of data and long processing times. Hopfully MS will fix the core problems sooner rather than later.
